# Sans/monospace font for `otherlanguage`

Tags: fonts, languages, polyglossia

Section 4, “Font setup”, in the [Polyglossia manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) provides:

> If a specific sans or monospace font is needed for a particular script or language, it can be defined by means of `\⟨script⟩fontsf` or `\⟨language⟩fontsf` and `\⟨script⟩fonttt` or `\⟨language⟩fonttt`, respectively.

It seems to me that this *only* holds true if the language for which the sans/monospace font is set is the `defaultlanguage`. That means, if I use

```
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{ukrainian}
```

and then set

```
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Cyrillic]
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial Black}[Script=Cyrillic]
```

Polyglossia will *not* select `Arial Black` when `\sffamily` is invoked in a Ukrainian environment but rather default back to the `\sffamily` for latin, as the log shows:

```
Missing character: There is no й in font [lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text!
```

I do not think this to be the expected behaviour but I could not find any hint in the Polyglossia source code as to why this is happening, either.

My question is, then, how can I set up specific sans or monospace fonts for languages other than the `defaultlanguage`?

---

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Cyrillic]
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{Arial Black}[Script=Cyrillic]

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{ukrainian}

\begin{document}
\begin{ukrainian}
\author{А.В. Тор}
\title{Великий об'єм }
\maketitle
\section{Перший}
\sffamily
\lipsum[1]
\end{ukrainian}
\sffamily
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```